# Multiple indeterminate checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have got the way to do indeterminate checkbox on [here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/indeterminate/)

But I'm looking for multiple indeterminate checkbox [like here](https://jsfiddle.net/arjunkneworld/fkut9wm2/)

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="option"><label for="option"> Electronics1</label>
      <ul>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> Laptops</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> TVs</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> Microphones</label></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="option"><label for="option"> Electronics2</label>
      <ul>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> Laptops</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> TVs</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> Microphones</label></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

.JavaScript:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.subOption'),
    checkall = document.getElementsByClassName('option');

for(j=0;j<checkall.length;j++) {
for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].onclick = function() {
    var checkedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input.subOption:checked').length;
    checkall[j].checked = checkedCount > 0;
    checkall[j].indeterminate = checkedCount > 0 && checkedCount < checkboxes.length;
  }
 }
}
```

Please help me to know better way to handle multiple nodes.

Comment: I have given the fiddle link on top, however **[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/arjunkneworld/fkut9wm2/)**

Comment: All the relevant code should be in the question itself. Please read [ask]. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read the errors that are waiting to be read.

Comment: Fine, can you help me to solve this question

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues in your code

- value of `i` and `j` are evaluated when onclick is executed, so their last value only will be bound to the event handler
- You were only checking the count of all checked boxes, not just those which are specific for one option

Try this

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input.subOption');

checkboxes.forEach(function( checkbox ) {
  checkbox.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var parentLi = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var parentCheckAll = parentLi.querySelector(".option");
    var checkedCount = parentLi.querySelectorAll('input.subOption:checked').length;
    var totalCount = parentLi.querySelectorAll('input.subOption').length;
    console.log(checkedCount, totalCount);
    checkedCount < totalCount && checkedCount > 0 ? (parentCheckAll.indeterminate = true) : (parentCheckAll.indeterminate = false, parentCheckAll.checked = checkedCount > 0 );
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="option">
      <label for="option"> Electronics1</label>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> Laptops</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> TVs</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> Microphones</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="option">
      <label for="option"> Electronics2</label>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> Laptops</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> TVs</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="subOption"> Microphones</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry it's not working, actually I'm looking for 3 state indeterminate checkbox on parent element in the solution

Comment: Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: @ARJUN This is working fine for me here. What do you mean by *actually I'm looking for 3 state indeterminate checkbox* ?

Comment: I'm looking for the [example given here](https://tympanus.net/codrops-playground/SaraSoueidan/G3GjvVlw/editor). The parent checkbox will be checked when all the child checkbox checked.

Comment: That is precisely what my code is doing. Please describe what output do you see in your machine and what fixes are required in them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159735/discussion-between-arjun-and-gurvinder372).

Comment: @ARJUN Did you checked this in any other browser (latest version)?